# Undefined properties when implementing interface

Tags: actionscript-3, interface

Here's my class signature:

```
public class YouTubeControls extends Controls implements IControls
```

`YouTubeControls` has a public var `foo`. This code:

```
 var controls:IControls = new YouTubeControls();  
 trace(controls.foo);
```

results in this error:

> Access of possibly undefined property foo through a reference with static type `IControls`.

My application is going to have other "Control" classes, so casting controls (`YouTubeControls(controls)`) won't work. How can I access `controls.foo`?

**Edit**
If I can't do this without casting, how do I handle the problem of needing to know which class to cast it as?

Comment: Do all your subclasses have the `foo` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trace(controls.foo);` is the same as calling `IControl(controls).foo` since you controls variable is declared to be of type `IControl`. The problem is that you did not give the `IControl` interface a getter function `foo`. Note, properties are not allowed in interfaces, only methods. See the other answers here.

Answer (score 1):

If `foo` is defined in `YouTubeControls`, you will not be able to access it through a reference to `IControls`.  If you change your code to this, it will work:

```
var ytControls:YouTubeControls = new YouTubeControls();
trace(ytControls.foo);
var controls:IControls = ytControls;
```

However, you mentioned that other controls may also have a `foo` property; if that's the case, then you should define that property in `IControls`, not `YouTubeControls`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to Flash Builder at the moment, but I believe that you should be able to do use the 'as' operator to test if the object is one class or another.

```
if ((controls as YouTubeControls) != null) //controls IS a YouTubeControls 
                                           //because it didn't return null
    trace((controls as YouTubeControls).foo);
else
    ...
```

The advantage to the 'as' operator is that it attempts to cast, but if it fails it returns null, while the other form of casting...

```
YouTubeControls(controls)
```

Will throw a runtime exception if controls cannot be cast as a YouTubeControls.

Answer (score 1):

If you have several IControls you may want to extend this interface.

```
    public interface IMyControl extends IControl
    {
        public function get foo():SomeType;
    }
```

And then

```
    public class YouTubeControls extends Controls implements IMyControl
```

in each of your controls class.